# Navigation Flow in android Fragment

Tags: android

Navigation Flow in android Fragment such as push and pop with proper example ,

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction4 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction4.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction4.replace(R.id.main_frame, passportFragment);
                fragmentTransaction4.commit();
```

Comment: what exactly your problem?

Comment: What you want today ? i am not able to see any querry